# Python - how to access instance properties in parent classes with super(<class>, self)?

Tags: python, class, super

Please explain why I cannot use `super(class, self)` to access the properties defined in the class higher in the class inheritance hierarchy, and how to access them.

According to the document, `super(class, self` should be returning a proxy object via which I can access the `def name()` in a parent class instance.

- [super([type[, object-or-type]])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)

> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or
> sibling class of type. This is useful for accessing inherited methods
> that have been overridden in a class.
>
> The object-or-type determines the method resolution order to be
> searched. The search starts from the class right after the type.
>
> For example, if **mro** of object-or-type is D -> B -> C -> A ->
> object and the value of type is B, then super() searches C -> A ->
> object.

I thought `super(Parent)` will give a proxy to the GrandParent object which has the `def name()`.

```
class GrandParent:
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = "grand parent"

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name


class Parent(GrandParent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._name = "parent"

    @property
    def name(self):
        return super().name


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._name = "child"

    @property
    def name(self):
        return super(Parent).name


print(Child().name)
---
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Without `(class, self)`, it returns ... the child property. Obviously I have not understood how `self` and `super` work in Python. Please suggest what resources to look into to fully understand the behavior and the design.

```
class GrandParent:
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = "grand parent"

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name


class Parent(GrandParent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._name = "parent"

    @property
    def name(self):
        return super().name


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._name = "child"

    @property
    def name(self):
        return super().name


print(Child().name)
---
child
```

Comment: There is no “super name”. All `name` properties just return `self._name`, of which there’s only one. Your object doesn’t have one `_name` attribute per parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `self` always refers to one and the same object. When you do `super().__init__()`, the `self` in the parent's `__init__` is your instance of `Child`. `GrandParent.__init__` just sets an attribute on that object. By chaining all those `__init__`s, you're in effect just doing this:

```
o = object()
o._name = 'grand parent'
o._name = 'parent'
o._name = 'child'
```

You're just *overwriting* the `_name` attribute, of which there's only one. All the different `@property`s just return the value of this one `_name` attribute, of which your object only has one, and whose value is `'child'`.

If you want your object to have a separate `_name` attribute per parent, you will actually have to create separate attributes. The easiest way is probably with Python's double-underscore [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) a.k.a. "private attributes":

```
>>> class A:
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.__foo = 'bar'
...   @property
...   def foo(self):
...     return self.__foo
...
>>> class B(A):
...   def __init__(self):
...     super().__init__()
...     self.__foo = 'baz'
...   @property
...   def foo(self):
...     return super().foo
... 
>>> B().foo
'bar'
>>> vars(B())
{'_A__foo': 'bar', '_B__foo': 'baz'}
```

The actual attributes are named `_A__foo` and `_B__foo` and thereby don't conflict with each other.